# In Asymptotic Analysis, Show That :- O( f(n) + g(n) ) = O( max{ f(n) , g(n) } ) 

Tags: algorithm, analysis, asymptotic-complexity

O represents Big-O.
O(g) : { f| f is non negative function 
            
there exists c,m where c and m are any constants
 
                      such that f(n) <= cg(n) for all n >= m }
               
    Show That :- O( f(n) + g(n) ) = O( max{ f(n) , g(n) } ) .

Comment: What's `C`? Is it `f(n) <= C g(n)`? (Also, you should probably format this as code.)

Comment: not homework solving last year's question paper stuck on this so please help might come this time again...

Comment: Shouldn't `m` appear in `f(n) <= cg(n)` ?

Answer (score 2):

This follows from max{f(n), g(n)} <= f(n) + g(n) <= 2*max{f(n), g(n)}.